# search files on a specific folder in Django

Tags: python, html, django

how to search  files  on a specific folder in Django 2.1.15w

i'm making a n an  web app, and i want user to select a variable file  only from on specific folder, how i should fix the header in Django  to show  on directory path,

happy to here any ideas

Comment: searching files on a specific folder is realized by functions like `os.listdir()`, `glob.glob()` which have nothing to do with Django. You can use Django as GUI - to get information from user and display results - but `Django` has nothing to do with rest - `"searching"`doesn't depend on Django.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.